# What does 'over-strait' mean? (1575 Late April, UK)

Tags: meaning-in-context, elizabethan-english

> ;for which most dutiful kind of dealing towards us, the same appearing most evidently to
>   proceed of a singular and an extraordinary zeal and devotion
>   you bear towards us, we could not in honor but by our
>   letters make known unto you in what great good part we
>   accept the same, and how sorry we were to see your honourable mind wounded with so just cause of grief as seemeth to have grown of our Deputy’s **over-strait** dealing towards you, to whom we have by our letters presently sent unto him signified how greatly we do `mislike` the same: as also commanded him not only to further hereafter your service to the uttermost of his power, but also to seek by all the means he may to repair the decay of your reputation and credit, that lately hath ensued by his hasty and violent breaking of the said enterprize

I guess that 'strait' here is an archaic spelling of the modern 'straight', but then how to deduce further? I tried [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=overstraight&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=r2-xVJSpB43_yQTFlYLYBg#q=overstraight+dictionary&start=00) to no avail. My guess: Figuratively, 'straight' means 'Not evasive; honest', based on [definition 3](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/straight). So 'overstraight = overly straight => overly honest. Yet this contradicts the fact that the Queen `mislike[s]` the Deputy's dealing, so the Deputy probably isn't being honest?

Comment: [*Strait*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/strait) (tight, narrow, strict)  and [*straight*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/straight) (uncurved, direct, honest) are not related.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic.  It would fit better on [ELU.SE]

Comment: I read it as *straight* but parsed it as *strict*, I didn't realise strait could **mean** strict. I like how I learn things about my own language on this site. :)

Comment: Where is the "deputy", and who and where is the "you" in "dealing towards you"?

Answer (score 1):

1. Forms    overstreit adj. [see below for streit]
   Etymology   From streit adj.
   Definitions (Senses and Subsenses)

1. 

(a) **Too precise, too rigorous; (b) too perilous, too severe.**

[*So, the dealing was not liberal.* It was one of those definitions above.]

In the margin [of this entry]: Related Dictionary Entries [I assume this is an alternate spelling too]
Oxford English Dictionary
(Please note that the OED is a subscription resource)

The earliest known use of the adjective over-strait is in the Middle English period (1150—1500).

OED's earliest evidence for over-strait is from before 1400, in the writing of Robert Mannyng, poet and historian.

over-strait is formed within English, by derivation.

Etymons: over- prefix, strait adj.

over-strait, adj. Opens in a new window

[University of Michigan_Middle English Dictionary](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED31995)

[2)
streit, adj., O.Fr. estreit ; strait, ' stricfus,'

' angustus, artus,' PR. p. 479; LA5. 22270;

Bek. 260 ; Ch. C. t. ^ 174 ; streit ))at is to

seie **narou** Mand. 45 ; strait ayenb. 54 ;

strei3t blind Trev. VI. 235 ; till a strdte

{sb.) thai held thair wai Barb. iv. 458 ;

strdtest {stiperl.) Barb. vi. 463.

straitnes, sb., **narrowness**, Barb. xii. 430.

3)
over-hand, -herre, -lej^er, -ling, -lippe,

-man, see under **uver**.

There are 708 entries with **over** in them, many under uver. Either before a verb, after a verb or alone or with a passed participle etc.

This dictionary is hard to understand for a non-specialist like myself but it does seem that strait aka streit means narrow.

To me this seems to mean the opposite of: overly liberal dealing with

[Middle English Dictionary](https://archive.org/details/middleenglishdic00stra/page/583/mode/1up?view=theater&q=angustus)

The dictionary is from Oxford University Press in 1891, it is by FRANCIS HENRY STRATMANN A NEW EDITION, RE-ARRANGED, REVISED, AND ENLARGED BY HENRY BRADLEY.]

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the larger context of this letter, I agree that the comments are likely correct and that "strait" here means "strict" or "by-the-rules."

In this letter, the Queen is apologizing because her Deputy (like an administrator), refused the Duke's request/offer of assistance. It seems that his offer may have been extravagant. The footnotes mention that he asked to serve under the Deputy and offered to enlist his private military forces in direct service to the Deputy. The Deputy refused these offers and the Duke got upset and (presumably) complained to the Queen about it.

We don't know all of the politics that would have been involved, but likely, the Deputy didn't want to have to work with the Duke and refused him on a technicality, which the Queen then overrode.

Answer (score -2):

English language and spelling has changed a bit in 440 years. Therefore I agree with @Jasper that this is a bit off topic for ELL.

The following explanation is my opinion. I don't claim to be an expert on archaic expressions and spelling.

The paragraph is a apology. The cause is "our Deputy’s over-strait dealing towards you". I agree with you that 'strait' is likely to be a different spelling of our word 'straight'. The sense is that the Deputy has been too straight and therefore rude by honesty. We might use blunt or outspoken. This would be consistent with use of mislike.

Comment: I thought this sounded like a reasonable answer, but looking at a larger piece of the context, that doesn't seem to be the meaning.

https://books.google.com/books?id=cJFCj3jd5xEC&pg=PA101&lpg=PA101&dq=%22grown+of+our+Deputy%E2%80%99s+over-strait+dealing+towards+you%22